# i18n localization in a React island of Astro js

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next, astrojs

My web is implemented in Astro, and I have a React island.
Localization is implemented in an astro middleware

```
export const initTranslation = defineMiddleware(async (context, next) => {
  await i18next.use(getLanguageDetector(context)).init({ resources: translationsData });
  return next();
});
```

And the language detector is

```
const getLanguageDetector = (context: APIContext): LanguageDetectorModule => {
  return {
    type: 'languageDetector',
    detect() {
      // Implement your custom logic to detect the user's language
      const localeParams = toLocalParams(context.params.localUrlPath);
      return localeParams?.locale ?? 'en_GB';
    },
  };
};
```

How should I implement the localization for the react island?

I can't pass the translation function to the island, only serialized props can be passed.
I tried a different i18n implementation, just for the react island, with a hook in the island to detect the language change:

```
export const i18nextReact = i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // Passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources: translationsData,
    lng: 'en_GB',
    fallbackLng: 'en_GB', // Use English if detection fails
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // React already escapes values
    },
  });
```

This solution works for the island, but the language detection change doesn't work in the rest of the astro app.

Now the workaround that I'm using is to pass to the island a map of the keys to be translated and the translation in the correct language. But in this way I'm loosing too many ICU functionalities (conditional translations, plurals, etc), so cannot be a long term solution...

I think the best solution should be with the different i18n implementation for react, without loosing language detection in astro, so probably I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: there's e.g. https://github.com/Alexandre-Fernandez/astro-i18n but I haven't tried it...

Comment: the current libraries with astro and i18n weren't applicable for our app, and in any case this should be possible to be implemented without additional libraries

Comment: it's certainly possible implementing it yourself without libs (even without i18next), but no out-of-the-box solution by astro – seems to be currently a weak spot of the framework.